# Как работать с bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите как bootstrap применять при верстке psd? Как изменять стили, подстраивать под себя?

Answer (score 1):

Читайте здесь всю документацию.
http://bootstrap-ru.com/
Стили можете дописывать к стилям Бутстрапа или в своём файле